# Search a string which contains backslash using Grep command

Tags: grep

In the tail output i have following string...Using grep command how can i search for the string `"contentState\":\"STOPPED\"`. I have to search for the whole string `"contentState\":\"STOPPED\"` rather
 than searching for STO`P`PED or `contentState` only.

I tried following command: But it is not working.

```
 grep -e ""contentState\":\"STOPPED\" /opt/logs/out.log | tail -1



 {\"eventType\":\"appAction\",\"action\":\"CONTENT_STATE_CHANGE\",\"evt\":{\"contentState\":\"STOPPED\"}}}
```

Comment: What's with all the slashes? does your `/opt/logs/out.log` contain a JSON string?

Comment: yes.....the log file contains json string as {\"eventType\":\"appAction\",\"action\":\"CONTENT_STATE_CHANGE\",\"evt\":{\"contentState\":\"STOPPED\"}}}

Comment: can you do `cat /opt/logs/out.log` and post its contents to the question and _not_ in the comments

Comment: The file size is more than 30mb so its bit difficult to paste contents here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for `"contentState\":\"STOPPED\"`, you need to (a) put the whole string in single-quotes to protect it, and (b) escape (double) the backslashes.  Thus:

```
grep -e '"contentState\\":\\"STOPPED\\"' /opt/logs/out.log
```

Without the protection provided the outer single-quotes, the unescaped double-quotes would be subject to the shell's *quote removal* and `grep` would never see them.

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat log
good "contentState\":\"STOPPED\"
bad contentState\":\"STOPPED\"
bad "contentState\":\"STOPPED"
```

Let's run our command:

```
$ grep -e '"contentState\\":\\"STOPPED\\"' log
good "contentState\":\"STOPPED\"
```

As we can see, the good line is returned and only the good line.

Comment: one more doubt in java how we declare this as string String LOG = '"contentState\\":\\"STOPPED\\"'; while declaring this getting invalid charecter constant

Comment: As I understood it, you were asking about using the utility `grep` at the shell command line.  How does Java entering into this?